# PHP multithread to call several soap servers

Tags: php, multithreading

I have to call a php function wich takes one second to response, in a "for" loop :

```
    for ($i=0; $i<count($wsdlTab); $i++)
    {
        $serverLoadTab[$i] = $this->getServerLoad($wsdlTab[$i]);
    }
```

My problem is that I would like to call my getServerLoad($wsdlTab[$i]) function simultaneous for each row of my $wsdlTab[$i], to not have to wait one second on each loop.

That is the reason why I need to call that function in a thread.

I have seen various ways to "emulate" threads, but I have not found any way with my limitations :

- I have to get the return value of my getServerLoad($wsdlTab[$i]), and put in in an array
- The Apache server is on Windows

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: For those with similar problem, try stream sockets; this might help: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2005/may/guru-multiplexing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't really have asynchronous or threading built-in, as you've discovered.

What I might do in a case like this is separate the script I need to execute in a parallel, putting it into its own, small and self-contained PHP file. Then I'd execute that in a separate thread, storing the result somewhere I could monitor in the original thread. Once all the scripts have returned and filled the results, or with some given timeout, I would then continue with processing.

So, for instance,

```
prepareResults(); // something like clearing a db row or zeroing out a file or whatever
for ($i=0; $i<count($wsdlTab); $i++) {
    exec('./doServerLoad.php ' . $wsdlTab[$i] . ' &');
}
while (!waitingForResults()) { // checking the results table/row/file
}
$serverLoadTab = parseTheResults();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will catch the results in a temp file and will get them right there.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Gearman for parallel processing: http://gearman.org/

Answer (score 0):

May be request WSDLs in multi threads/forks using [`pcntl_fork()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) or [`curl_multi`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php), and save them to the local drive. Then just parse them:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient('WSDLSTemp/wsdl1.wsdl');
// .. do whatever you want...
```